# Spring Data Flow support for Aurora and Mesos

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

Is there any plans to support Aurora and Mesos similar to Marathon and Mesos ?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Maybe you should ask the Aurora or Mesos support / community on this issue. StackOverflow is platform to ask for specific programming problems, read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

We do not have any near-term plans for Aurora. With what we have learned from community interaction, we've taken the opinionated view of Marathon as the out-of-the-box experience.

That said, if there's a java-client for Aurora, it is fairly straightforward to add your own `spring-cloud-deployer-mesos` [implementation](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-deployer-mesos), which in turn can be consumed by Spring Cloud Data Flow's [mesos-server](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-mesos) implementation. Feel free to submit a pull request and we would happy to collaborate.